# R - create new .csv column using values calculated from other column

Tags: r, csv

I have a column of values (CO2.Value..PPM), and want to create a new column (co2_new) that is the result of taking each value from the first column and scaling it. Here's what I was trying:

```
c$co2_new = 0.0
for (i in c$co2_new){
  i = i + ((c$CO2.Value..PPM.-(-24.395))/1.074)
  return i
}
head(c$co2_new)
```

But it returns an error (unexpected symbol) and the column still only contains 0. I feel like this is simple, but i haven't been able to make it work yet!

Comment: Your code definetly won't work. You don't return inside for loops, and if you would, it would be `return()`. Also you're changing the counter value of the loop and hoping it will magically replace the values in the new column. Try this: `c$co2_new <- 1:nrow(c) + (c$CO2.Value..PPM. - (-24.395))/1.074`

Comment: I suggest you take read some introductory R materials to better understand R's syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things in your code that are either wrong or not good.

1. Though not prohibited, it is generally bad form to use `c` as a variable name; though *R* will understand the difference between your variable `c` and the base function `c` (to concatenate), it's visibly confusing when reading your code.

   In fact, there are many who dislike single-letter variables for important variables (some say *any* variables); perhaps the use of `i` is acceptable in small loops, but even then some disagree with it.

   The rationale is based heavily on sharing and maintenance of code. If you were to look at things in few months or a year, would it be perfectly clear what is in your `c`, what it meant semantically, etc?
2. Don't use `return` in a `for` loop unless it is within a function and you intend to break out of the `for` loop and the function, both. Specifically, your intended action in the `for` loop is to take the value from one specific position in `$CO2.Value..PPM`, scale it, and then assign that value into the same position in `$co2_new`. In this case, your `for` loop variable should really be an index within the vector, not the value itself, so that you can reference the position within both vectors. Perhaps (and this is not good code, based on my number 3 below):

   ```
   c$co2_new = 0.0
   for (i in 1:length(c$co2_new)) {
       c$co2_new[i] = c$co2_new[i] + ((c$CO2.Value..PPM.[i] -(-24.395))/1.074)
   }
   ```
3. There is no need to loop, as @Molx said, and it is a significant thing to learn and understand when programming in *R*. The assignment can be done in one fell swoop, because when you do math with a vector, the same math is done to every value within it. So the above `for` loop can be replaced with:

   ```
   c$co2_new = 0.0
   c$co2_new = c$co2_new + ((c$CO2.Value..PPM. - (-24.395))/1.074)
   ```
4. Perhaps an artifact of your example, but you do not need to initialize the new column. You could simplify this code even further to:

   ```
   ## no need for c$co2_new = 0.0
   c$co2_new = (c$CO2.Value..PPM. - (-24.395))/1.074
   ```